# Graphing two lines in Google Sheets based on values in first column

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-charts, pivot

I'm trying to create two lines on the same graph, with one being 'Line A' based on Data labeled 'A' and 'Line B' based on B.

The X-axis would be the date and would expand over time as more entries were added. The weight would be the Y-axis.

I can't seem to convince Google sheets to separate out the data based on the 'Name' column into two lines. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: An example of data I'm trying to graph with two lines]

Answer (score 3):

- your data should be in this format:

[image: 0]

---

- if this is not the option you can transform it with this formula:

```
=QUERY(A1:C, "select B,sum(C) where A is not null group by B,C pivot A", 1)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Is there a way to do the same where the data for A and B would be on different sets of dates? My data is structured in the same way as your first image but A and B occur on different dates, this results in dots rather than lines.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oeV78Rnqt2u_KTpnWNfBwdZX0O1gBEq1VaN6hYDtPtg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @ChrisA https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Dvd0.png

Comment: Great work, thanks!