# Setting the scale of the horizontal axis in time units, for plotting multiple time series, in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, time-series

I have some timestamped data from various sensors.  All the sensors measure the same system, but the sample times are not correlated.  The data may even have gaps

[image: two time series one Excel or Google sheet graph]

To plot the above I placed that data into columns:

```
Hot  Cold   Time
     31.9   2022-08-10 00:05:40
16.9        2022-08-10 00:09:43
     32.4   2022-08-10 00:21:01
     31.9   2022-08-10 00:23:11
```

But what I'd like is a more usable horizontal (time) axis, with human readable increments of time.  Thus the time axis might have minor ticks every two minutes, with major ticks every 30 minutes.

This this possible?  If not in Google Sheets what might be a good tool for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Graphing two lines in Google Sheets based on values in first column](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/130979/graphing-two-lines-in-google-sheets-based-on-values-in-first-column)

Comment: @Tedinoz no.  I am looking for a horizontal axis of real time, regardless of how the data is clustered.  Some days may have 10 sample points, other days 1000's.

Comment: Your sample graph doesn't include **ANY** dates on the x-axis. How can one fine-tune values on the x-axis when there are no values to fine-tune. Every event requires a date (howsoever determined) and, when you set the data range for the graph, the date field must be the leftmost field of the three. Perhaps you already know this and you may feel this discussion is unnecessary. If that is the case, then would you please edit your question to display a graph with dates on the x-axis so that volunteers can focus on that aspect.